# error trying to download install file in Ubuntu through Python

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm totally new to command line and am trying to follow the instructions [here](http://rleca.pbworks.com/w/file/fetch/124098201/tuto_obitools_install_W10OS.html) to get OBITools installed. I've gotten part way through, but I am getting an error I don't understand when trying to download the OBITools install file. The code presented in the tutorial is:

`wget http://metabarcoding.org//obitools/doc/_downloads/get-obitools.py python get-obitools.py`

I am getting the following error:
`>>> wget http://metabarcoding.org//obitools/doc/_downloads/get-obitools.py File "<stdin>", line 1 wget http://metabarcoding.org//obitools/doc/_downloads/get-obitools.py ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to type those lines at the python shell (the one with >>>), you're supposed to type those into your regular bash shell (the one with $).

Answer (score 0):

Type `exit()` to quit from the python shell and try again